# String to object to same string format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have this string:

`16.12.2018`

Then I create an object from it and add one day, like this:

```
var mindate = new Date(mindate.split('.').reverse().join(','));
if (mindate.getDay() == 0) { // If it is Friday  
    mindate.setDate(mindate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

The result is: `Mon Dec 17 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`

Is it possible to return same string from new Date, aka `17.12.2018`, without using additional libraries?

Comment: Just extract the date/month/year from the date object, and format it appropriately?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, this is solution, but I looking for some method for format of dates in JS

Comment: It basically comes down to this: If there's a locale format that matches what you want, you can use `.toLocaleDateString( someLocale )`. Else you better off with writing your own formatting function as shown below and in the duplicates, since it'll be easier to work with than trying to force one of the toString functions to respect the format you want through their options.

Comment: @Shilly Yeah, but I come from PHP where have very good options for formating of Date objects, so I looking for something like it, but .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do the following :

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "01", "02", "03",
    "04", "05", "06", "07",
    "08", "09", "10",
    "11", "12"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + '.' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '.' + year;
}

var mindate = "16.12.2018";
mindate = new Date(mindate.split('.').reverse().join(','));
if (mindate.getDay() == 0) { // If it is Friday  
    mindate.setDate(mindate.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(formatDate(mindate))
```

Comment: `('0'+monthIndex).slice(-2)` will 0 pad for you without an array.

Comment: @kabanus your answer would give `17.11.2018` and not `12` but yeah I got your point that it can be simplified :)

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with mindate;

```
var dateString = mindate.getDate() + '.'+ Number(mindate.getMonth()+1)+'.'+ mindate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Glad to see it worked :0